# xsd to entity model (ejb3)

Tags: xsd, entity

I wonder if somebody knows if there is a framework somewhere out there tha can convert from XSD to entity model.

thank kiu..

Answer (score 0):

look for HyperJaxb3

Answer (score 0):

.Net Entity Framework should do it.